# AWS EC2 LoadBalancing SSL nodeJS - Where am I going wrong

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am fairly new to all this (being an app/mobile web developer).

I have setup an instance on EC2 which runs perfectly under http.

I want to add https support as I want to write a service worker.

I have used Amazons Certificate Manager to obtain a certificate
I have created an ELB and added a listener at 443 for https

I am not entirely sure whether my ELB and EC2 instance are connected.  Following some instructions I attempted to create a CNAME rule in my Route53 setup but it would not accept it (pointing to the ELB DNS).

My understanding is that if they are then my http nodejs instance should now automatically support https.

This is currently not the case.  My nodejs code is unchanged (it still only creates a http server listening at port 3002.

When I do a http call to the domain (http://example.com:3002) it works but a https call (https://example.com:3002) does not with a Site can not be reached failure.

This leads me to believe that the ELB and the EC2 are not associated.  Can anyone suggest where I may have gone wrong as I have hunted the internet for 3 days and not found any step by step instructions for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on this part of your question:

> I am not entirely sure whether my ELB and EC2 instance are connected.
>   Following some instructions I attempted to create a CNAME rule in my
>   Route53 setup but it would not accept it (pointing to the ELB DNS).

Why are you not sure they are connected? You should be able to look at the health check section in the load balancer UI and see that the server instance is "connected" and healthy. If it isn't, then that is the first thing you need to fix.

Regarding the CNAME in Route53, what do you mean it wouldn't accept it? What are the details of that issue? Until you have your DNS pointing to the load balancer you won't actually be using the load balancer, so that's another issue you need to fix.

> When I do a http call to the domain (http://example.com:3002) it works
>   but a https call (https://example.com:3002) does not with a Site can
>   not be reached failure.

If you had an error setting up the DNS then of course this isn't going to work. You shouldn't even be attempting to test this yet until you get the DNS configured.

Comment: Focusing on the CNAME issue in Route53.  I attempted to create a new RecordSet.  I left the name blank.  I selected CNAME from Type and pasted the DNS for the ELB into the value.

Comment: If you leave the name blank it can't be a CNAME, because it's not a subdomain. You need to create an A record, select "alias" and then select the ELB from the list of available aliases. Also, please include the error message when asking for help with errors.

Comment: Great, I have created an A record rather than CName.  
I have also setup a health check and I can see that http traffic is healthy, but https traffic is not.  It is giving this error:
Failure: The connection was closed by the endpoint

Comment: How do you have the HTTPS listener configured?

Comment: My EC2 instance has four security groups.  Focusing on the one with the same VPC id as the ELB.  I have two listeners.
Firstly one is the generic one that is always there.

Comment: I added a second which listens on https.  The port is automatically set at 443

Comment: This is an inbound listener

Comment: the source is set to 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I didn't ask how your security groups are configured. How are you ELB listeners configured? Do you have an HTTPS listener in the ELB? What port is it forwarding to on your EC2 instance?

Comment: Sorry thats my ignorance.  I have two listeners.  One is http.  the second is https.  That one has the certificate from IAM in it and a rule that points to the IAM instance that I created.It points to the ELB target group that I have setup for https (port 443).

Comment: If your server isn't listening on port 443, then why create a target group for port 443? You should most likely be using the same target group that you are using for the HTTPS listener.

Comment: Can't keep apologising for my stupidity !!  

I created a new target group that is listening for https on 3002.  I have then pointed my listener to that target group.  However, should the listener also be set to 3002 or should it remain as 443?

Comment: The listener needs to be 443, the default HTTPS port, if you don't want the user having to specify a port in the browser. The load balancer listens on that port, and then forwards to whatever port your app is listening to.

Comment: OK so I have the ELB listener set to 443 (https) and pointing to a target which is set to 3002.

Health checks are still showing http as healthy and https as not.

What can I check next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126532/discussion-between-thethought-and-mark-b).